# (PyOpenGL) How do I rotate the camera around an object?

Tags: python, 3d, camera, rotation, pyopengl

I'm trying to create a program that simulates movement around an environment in a realistic manner, with pitch, roll, and yaw controls to move the camera around.
I had previously attempted to create the illusion of movement, but realized rotation isn't possible, because as the object being rotated stays in the view.
At the moment I'm using pygame to handle windows.

I have no idea of where to start, and I'm new to OpenGL, and a bit of a python novice.

Thanks in advance, I really do need this.

Comment: I don't know about **Py**OpenGL specifically, but usually camera movement is handled by applying reversed transformations to the whole scene. That is, turning the camera in a direction by 30° is the same as turning the whole scene in the opposite direction by 30°.

Comment: I understand that, but I need to make it appear as if the camera is rotating away. I need the scene to go out of view as the camera "rotates".